# Styling a form with flexbox -- labels overflowing nested flexbox divs

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

This may be a duplicate but I've waded through about 20 "flexbox overflowing children" questions here on stackoverflow without finding the answer to my specific question... So if this *is* a duplicate and somebody's already answered this particular question I'd really, really appreciate a link :) Thanks in advance for any advice :)

---

I'm styling a pre-generated form, and altering the html isn't practical in this case. There *has* to be a simple, I-can't-believe-I-overlooked-that-! css solution to this...

My intention with this styling is that I want each individual label to remain on one line if at all possible, rather than squishing narrower and wrapping. If that means that one radio button + label stretches the full width of the form, fine, but I only want a label to wrap if it (plus the radio input) is wider than the form. Meanwhile, if the form-item divs can't all fit on one line I'd like them to wrap as necessary. I'm using nested flexboxes because I want the ability to vertically center my radio buttons and labels. Unfortunately, depending on the width of the containing element, the "form-item" divs are squishing themselves to all fit on one line and the labels within them are overflowing!

I've simplified the form down to a very basic test case. You can [see it on codepen](https://codepen.io/margaret-claypool/pen/eYmNxeQ). Here's the html and scss:

html:

```
<form>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-item form-item--1">
            <input type='radio' id='item1' name='group'>
            <label for='item1'>The quick brown fox</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item form-item--2">
            <input type='radio' id='item1' name='group'>
            <label for='item1'>The quick brown fox</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item form-item--3">
            <input type='radio' id='item1' name='group'>
            <label for='item1'>The quick brown fox</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item form-item--4">
            <input type='radio' id='item1' name='group'>
            <label for='item1'>The quick brown fox</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

scss:

```
.container {
    // setting the container div to a width that provokes this issue... 
    max-width: 45em; 

    // the form-item child divs should be wrapping at this width, but instead their contents are overflowing!!!
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.form-item {    
    // put 20px between this element and the next element to the right
    margin-right: 20px; 
    // make each div at least as wide as its content, and have them expand to fill all available space.
    flex: 1 0 auto; 

    display: flex; // <-- If the form-item divs are not flexboxes, the contents do *not* overflow. Instead the last div wraps as desired. Of course, then the contents are not vertically centered, and the flex-bases of the input and labels are ignored. For those reasons, I *really* want to use display: flex here!!! 

    input {
        // make the radio button take up exactly 25px of horizontal space
    flex: 0 0 25px;
    }

    label {     
        // make the label at least as wide as its content, and have it expand to fill all available space.
        flex: 1 0 auto; 
    }
}



// styling to better display the situation, but shouldn't affect the issue. (You can comment all the following out, and the labels are still overflowing their form-item parent div)
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    height: 100px;
}

.form-item {
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px dashed green;
    height: 50px;

    label {
        border: 1px dashed orange;
    }
}
```

Comment: Set `.form-item label { flex: 1;}`

Comment: @Awais, thanks but that's not quite the effect I'm looking for... flex: 1 is equivalent to flex-grow: 1, flex-shrink: 1, and flex-basis: auto. So the labels shrink as needed and the label text ends up wrapping inside the labels, rather than the form-item divs wrapping to a new line. It looks like Artur found a working solution, but I have no idea why it works!!! If you've got any insight, maybe comment on his solution, cause I'd love to know why the heck it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the following code. The change is pretty subtle as you suspected. I merely changed the style of the input from using a `flex-basis` of 25px to `auto`
and set a width of 25px instead.

`SCSS`

```
.container {
    max-width: 45em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.form-item {    
    margin-right: 20px;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: flex; 

    input {
        width: 25px;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }

    label {
        flex: 1 0 auto; 
    }
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    height: 100px;
}

.form-item {
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px dashed green;
    height: 50px;

    label {
        border: 1px dashed orange;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Ok, I'm marking this as solving my problem, cause it totally works, but if you can add any insight into *why* I'd really appreciate it. Just adding `width: 25px` makes the flexboxes behave as they should, even without changing the flex attribute. It was my understanding that if a flex child has both a width attribute and a flex-basis, the flex-basis overrides the width. (See Dave Geddes' [The Difference Between Width and Flex Basis](https://gedd.ski/post/the-difference-between-width-and-flex-basis/)) So why would adding a width attribute change the flexbox layout and solve my overflow???

Comment: To be honest, I was playing around with your code and since I never used a value other than `auto` for `flex-basis` I made an educated guess and it worked. I am not sure yet why width works and flex-basis does not. As soon as I have figured this out I will add some insight to my answer.